# Issues accessing socialauth via ajax

Tags: ajax, socialauth

I am developing a server side web app using spring socialauth library by 3 pillars lab.

When accessing this web app using href in  an anchor tag, I am able to invoke the 3rd party application (in my case, facebook) page.

But when i tried calling it using jquery ajax I got "Allow origin header error". On searching for this error, I found out that this error is due to the ajax calling page and the URL, it is trying to call, being on different domains. I have changed the headers in my webapp as: "allow origin to *". After this, my webapp does not throw this "allow origin header" error but now 3rd party app is throwing this error.

I have tried two types of Cross domain ajax method :

1. JSONP: with this i am able to hit even 3rd party url via ajax but it is throwing an error
   "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html"
   As per my understanding, it is throwing error because this method expects JSONP as response instead getting text/html in response.
2. CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing):
   In this also, facebook is throwing allow origin header.

I want to make ajax call to facebook using my webapp that uses socialauth library and it should display facebook page. Plus i dont want to redirect it.

I am stuck at this. Please help.